# Google maps, cluster below marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

Have anybody hints, how to put a cluster below and StyledMarker onto chluster, like in image:
[image].

I use markerClustererPlusV3.js and StyledMarker.js.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that a lot of Overlays in Google Maps have a `zIndex` option (and a `setIndex()` method so) :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

> All markers are displayed on the map in order of their zIndex, with
>   higher values displaying in front of markers with lower values. By
>   default, markers are displayed according to their vertical position on
>   screen, with lower markers appearing in front of markers further up
>   the screen.

:)